# Called program writing or defining variables in the calling program?

Tags: cobol, method-call

Is it possible for a called program to define new variables that can be accessed by the calling program upon return from the called program? I'm analyzing some Cobol code and see that after calling a program there is suddenly reference to a variable terminated in `-RET-CODE` which is not defined anywhere in the calling program.

UPDATE: It seems to be a variable defined in a copybook. See comments at the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the called program cannot add variables to the calling program.

The compiler can pre-define internal special variables.  For instance, in Microfocus Extend, the `RETURN-CODE` variable is always available and will be set to the value from the `EXIT PROGRAM RETURNING return-value` statement.

If you need more than just that numeric value, then you would call the subprogram with `BY REFERENCE` variables.  You then define the variables in both programs, the calling program anywhere and the called program in the `LINKAGE SECTION`.

Comment: Is it possible to define variables outside the program in a copybook so that different programs/procedures can read/write common variables?

Comment: Yes, you can define variables in copybooks, and, in fact, that is very common, especially in big production programs to make sure that things passed between programs are identical.  Use the `COPY` statement in linkage section in the called program and anywhere in the calling program.